# Veracode CWE id 611

Tags: veracode

I have  a piece of code where there is veracode finding for Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference ('XXE') Attack.

Code:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
        transformer.transform(source, result); //CWE ID 611, impacted line.
```

I used

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformer.setOutputProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

The issue got resolved with the following code:

```
        TransformerFactory transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance();//.newTransformer();
        transformer.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        transformer.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
        transformer.newTransformer().transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note for anyone running the application on JDK5 or older that you will not have these XML Constants available:

```
transformer.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformer.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

Instead you will have to parse to a Document using a secured document builder then use a DOM source in your transformer.

```java
private static void example(String xmlDocument, Result result) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, TransformerException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String s, String s1) throws SAXException, IOException {
            return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
        }
    });
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDocument)));

    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(domSource, result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is advised to put a try-catch block.

```
try{
            transformer.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
            transformer.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //jaxp 1.5 feature not supported
        }
```